# What protocols should support a bluetooth device to be operated from android application?

Tags: android, bluetooth

My customer is developing a bluetooth device. I am developing an android application which will operate this device (sending some commands using BluetoothSocket, receiving information from the device).
My application should work on all android devices with Android OS 2+.

So my question is: what techologies/protocols should support the bluetooth device to be operable via android bluetooth api 2+?

I am not very well with hardware. I just have to say customer the technical requirements for the device, how can I state these technical requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bluetooth Serial port profile should be sufficient on the device side for your app to talk to the device. 
The Android BluetoothSocket is Serial Port Profile API.

The need to work on all Android devices is a rather open requirement, Android device makers sometimes use different bluetooth hardware and software on their devices and though it may be the same Android API level the behavior might be different. So you will have to test on devices which you expect to work/support.